# Retorno Json api acento

Tags: php, json

Estou usando uma `api` que retorna dados em `json`. Todos os acentos estão vindo modificados.

```
J\u00FAnior
```

Com `php`, qual a função que posso utilizar para reverter esta situação?

**Apesar de já ter desfeito ele, ele se assemelhava a este.*

**CÓDIGO:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Search approved payments in last month</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        require_once "../../lib/mercadopago.php";

        $mp = new MP("XXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        // Sets the filters you want
        $filters = array(
            //"range" => "date_created",
            //"begin_date" => "NOW-1MONTH",
            //"end_date" => "NOW",
           // "status" => "approved",
            //"operation_type" => "regular_payment"
        );

        // Search payment data according to filters
        $searchResult = $mp->search_payment($filters);

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($searchResult);
        echo "</pre>";

        // Show payment information
        ?>
        <table border='1'>
            <tr><th>id</th><th>site_id</th><th>date_created</th><th>operation_type</th><th>external_reference</th></tr>
            <?php
            foreach ($searchResult["response"]["results"] as $payment) {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $payment["collection"]["id"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $payment["collection"]["site_id"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $payment["collection"]["date_created"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $payment["collection"]["operation_type"]; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $payment["collection"]["external_reference"]; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você não precisa reverter, esse é o código unicode do caractere, é exatamente a forma mais compatível de lidar com caracteres especiais. O PHP consegue depois traduzir isso para texto comum.

Comment: sim, quando vc printar isso no html ele converte para acento sozinho

Comment: Mas em meu caso ele não está fazendo isso... está printando desse jeito... A página esta em UTF8...

Comment: Isso é problema no client, não no server. Posta o **trecho** do código que você usa pra receber os dados da API.